# how to change the color of a portion of QwtCurvePlot?

Tags: qt, qwt

I'm using `QwtCurvePlot` to plot a 2d graph. the y axis range is 0 to 100 and x axis is 0 to 60. I use `SetRawSamples` to initialize my data. say I want to change the colors of portion of graph that y value is between 50 and 60. is there any one can help me please?

EDIT: I want something like [image: this]

Comment: That portion of graph get color static or dynamic like user select that area ?

Comment: It is static. but that portion dose not have data all the time.

Comment: Your question is so different than your screenshot !?

Comment: my question is equivalent to green area in the screenshot's plot. excuse me if I was not clear. but I need to implement other parts later. if you know a better library, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you should reimplement **QwtPlotZoneItem** draw function in horizontal orientation.If you think you need more in-depth answer comment me.